# routeProvider doesn't work and controller undefined using angularjs 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, controller, route-provider

I'm working on my first app. When I open it in the webbrowser I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: controller is not defined
    at app.js:3
    at app.js:15

I got this error after I created the app.js file and tried to link my controller.js to it. Also the routeProvider doesn't seem to work yet. And my placeholders stopt working, which did work before.

I simplified my code to keep it readable. I've got more html files and use bootstrap in combination with JQuery and CSS. Does someone know what's going wrong here?

**app.js**

```
(function(){

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',     ['ngRoute']).controller('controller', controller)

    .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: '../main.html',
                controller: 'controller'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '../main'});

});
})();
```

**controller.js**

```
     (function() {
         angular.module('controller', ['ngRoute'])
             .controller('controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        }]);
    })();
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app = "myApp">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title> Who Brings What </title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
/*more code here */
    </nav>
</div>

<div data-ng-view></div>

<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js">    </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-    route.js"></script>
<!--<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-   route.js">    </script>-->
<script src = "../controller.js"></script>
<script src = "../app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**main.html**

```
<div>
    Main Body
</div>
```

Comment: too many mistakes in this code

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues with your code,

(i)Since you have defined controller separately in a single file, you can safely remove it from the initial module.

```
function(){
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/main', {
            templateUrl: './main.html',
                controller: 'controller'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});
});
})();
```

(ii) You do not need to have ngRoute injected twice, You can just use the globally declared module

```
 (function() {
           app.controller('controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
        }]);
 })();
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xUHyS0WLan93YZzz2iMS?p=preview)**